# Django Error while rendering template IndexError

Tags: django, django-admin

I just deployed my Django application with nginx and gunicorn, everything is running fine with every model, but for a model admin template is giving an error while rendering template. I have pasted Trace-back below.

[image]

Comment: Don't use screenshots, instead post the complete stack trace in code format ! This will help one to debug easily!

Comment: look like c1 is not having any data

Comment: @vivekpradhan it is CL = change list , and not c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vivek is right, In admin.py I have written code for MyModelAdmin and for some of it's records doesn't have a value for a field. I have fixed by putting an if condition.